# How to change placement of block or region on events?

Tags: theming, 8

I want to change the placement of 2 regions based on window size. I know that I can print 2 blocks and use css `dipslay:none` based on window size, but I prefer not to double print a block.

Is there any way I can change the placement of blocks / regions based on events, such as screen size, using JS or similar?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flexbox order property: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/

Comment: I think this will only work to reorder blocks within same region, but not so put them into another region.

Comment: What I was thinking to suggest this was to arrange the regions themselves. If that is not the case, than it was my misunderstanding :p

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this using js `$('#source').appendTo('#destination');`
I'm not sure if this is the drupalish way to do it? But at least it works!

I found it from this page;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element